# SQL Date Range Not Using Between

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a sql query with a date range filter.  I was using BETWEEN but I am not receiving the correct return on records.  The table I a querying tracks employee status. An employee can be active one month and inactive the next month and then back to active the following month.  I am not sure how to only show when the employee was active. If there is no end date, the employee is active.
So in the example below, employee 11111 was NOT active in January, active in February and Not active in March.  Employee 22222 is currently active and has been since January.
This table links to another table of tests that they have entered, so my SQL is to return the tests that they entered only during the time the were active.

Example data:

```
EMPLOYEE TABLE
EmployeeID     StartDate     EndDate
11111          01/01/2021    01/30/2021
11111          02/01/2021
11111          03/01/2021    03/31/2021
22222          01/01/2021

TEST TABLE
TestID     EnteredBy     Date 
1           11111        01/01/2021
2           11111        02/01/2021
3           11111        02/11/2021
4           11111        03/01/2021
5           22222        01/01/2021
6           22222        02/12/2021
7           22222        03/13/2021
```

Expected output:

```
TestID     EnteredBy     Date
2           11111        02/01/2021
3           11111        02/11/2021
5           22222        01/01/2021
6           22222        02/12/2021
7           22222        03/13/2021
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output also?

Comment: Updated - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is a bad design, you better fix your data design , but if data in employee table is one month per row then you can do this :

```
select *
from employees e
join testTable t
 on e.EMPLOYEE = t.EnteredBy
 and t.Date >= e.startDate and t.date <= DateSerial(Year(t.Date),Month(t.Date),0)
 and e.Enddate is null
```

so this query check if t.date is between e.startdate  and calculate last day of month based on startdate